# Magento 2: Override/Rewrite Block, Model, Controller, Helper using Plugin & Preference

Tags: magento2

Magento 2: Override/Rewrite Block, Model, Controller, Helper using Plugin & Preference.

How to override helper, block, model view?

Answer (score 5):

There are two step to override Block, Model And Controller file

1) Add override preference in di.xml

2) Create block,model and controller file in your module

> Namespace: Prince
>
> Module Name: Helloworld

**For override catalog product ListProduct block.**

1) Create di.xml file in Folder Prince/Helloworld/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Prince\Helloworld\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product" />
</config>
```

2) Create ListProduct.php Block file in Folder Prince/Helloworld/Block/Rewrite/Product

```
<?php
    namespace Prince\Helloworld\Block\Rewrite\Product;

    class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {
        public function _getProductCollection()
        {
            // Do your code here
        }
    }
```

**For override catalog product model.**

1) Add preference in di.xml before

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Prince\Helloworld\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product" />
```

2) Create Product.php Model file in Folder Prince/Helloworld/Model/Rewrite/Catalog

```
<?php
namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model\Rewrite\Catalog;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function isSalable()
    {
        // Do your code here

        return parent::isSalable();
    }

}
```

**For Overriding Controller**

1) Add preference in di.xml before

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Prince\Helloworld\Controller\Rewrite\Product\View" />
```

2) Create View.php Controller file in Folder Prince/Helloworld/Controller/Rewrite/Product

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // Do your stuff here
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

You can override other block,model and controllers using same approach.

Comment: and dont forget: if you rewrite a block maybe magento2 wont find your template, so you have to override the template also or call it via Vendor_Module::path/template.phtml